# .net core identity auth doesn't work for different ports

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have Angular + .NET Core app with Identity (Cookie Authentication).

When I launch it on one port, for example `http://localhost:5000` - auth works fine.

But if I launch Angular app on `localhost:4200` and .NET Core app on `localhost:5000` then - auth doesn't work, just show user isn't authenticated without any errors.

Of course I added `apiUrl` in Angular app `environment.ts` file to use different ports.

As I understand, cookie shares between different ports, but not domains, am I right or no?

What's wrong?

Is it normal behavior?

Or I miss any settings?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. If you start the Angular app independently, then you need to replace `spa.UseAngularCliServer` invocation with the following

```
spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
```

More detail, please refer to the document below:

[Run "ng serve" independently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-ng-serve-independently)